# Use KeePass to generate AWS MFA codes (TOTP / Time-Based One-Time Password)

Tags: amazon-web-services, keepass, two-factor-authentication

We use in our team KeePass to store the credentials and the MFA secret key of AWS account root users.

Is it possible to use KeePass to directly generate the AWS MFA codes (TOTP / Time-Based One-Time Password)? Otherwise, every team member would have to add every MFA secret key inside an authenticator app (like `Microsoft Authenticator` or `Google Authenticator`) to generate the needed MFA codes during login.

Comment: Generally root accounts should be used very rarely for exceptional events that can't be done by an administrator. It would be better to give your admins an IAM user with admin rights, or federate to a central identity store. Two or three people can then add root MFA to their own authenticator app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeePass` provides, since version 2.x, an option ([{TIMEOTP} – Generating Time-Based One-Time Passwords](https://keepass.info/help/base/placeholders.html#otp)) for generating AWS MFA codes out of the box. 
Simply go to the advance tab and add the `String fields`:

- Name: `MFA Code` / Value: `{TIMEOTP}`
- Name: `TimeOtp-Secret` (use `TimeOtp-Secret-Base32` for AWS MFA secret keys) / Value: `12345678901234567890`

[image: KeePass Advanced String fields]

There will appear a new option called `MFA Code` inside the context menu with the current MFA code.

[image: Copy MFA Code]